# How to access x and y values from a jQuery XY pad

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this jQuery library called jQuery Control. https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Kontrol
the XY pad gives me a value like this :

```
Object {x: 112, y: 77}
```

how can i access x and y separately and use them for different parameters.
here is the complete code : http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/Hs5ff/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = JSON.parse($(".xy").val());
console.log(obj.x); // 112
console.log(obj.y); // 77
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. but another problem i have ( i think its because of the plugin itself ) is that i does not change value in real time when the mouse is clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/ehsanziya/Hs5ff/3/

Comment: i used the draw method which seems like is more responsive. but still does not update the value till i release the mouse

Answer (score 0):

```
'change' : function(x){
        gain.gain.value = 1;
        console.log(x, x.x, x.y);   

}
```

In the code, `x` is an object with `x` and `y` properties. You can access the individual values with `x.x` and `x.y`.

Comment: 'change' : function(x){ gain.gain.value = x.x; }